# How to redirect / convert any URL to lowercase?

Tags: htaccess, url, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On   
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But I want to rewrite all UPPERCASE characters to lowercase characters, e.g:

- OLD: `/myfolder-sample-URL.html`
- NEW: `/myfolder-sample-url.html`

Comment: To implement such redirect using mod_rewrite and .htaccess you need to use **RewriteMap** directive which cannot be placed in .htaccess -- only in server config / VirtualHost context. Do you have access to server config? Can you change it? If no -- then you can only implement it when executing the actual page (using PHP/ASP.NET etc).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Yes I have access to RewriteMap, so... what should I do now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To implement such redirect using mod_rewrite and .htaccess you need to use `RewriteMap` directive which cannot be placed in .htaccess -- only in server config / VirtualHost context. If you have such access:

**1.** Place this line inside `<VirtualHost>` block for your site:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

**2.** Place this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) **any URL that has at least 1 capital letter** (Latin letters only) **in path part of URL** (query string is ignored) to the same but in lower case.

**For example:**

```
http://mydomain.com/myfolder-sample-URL.html
=> 
http://mydomain.com/myfolder-sample-url.html

http://mydomain.com/myfolder-sample-url.HTML
=> 
http://mydomain.com/myfolder-sample-url.html
```

but will do nothing for these URLs:

```
http://mydomain.com/myfolder-sample-url.html?say=MEOW
http://MYDOMAIN.com/myfolder-sample-url.html
```

**If you want to restrict it to .html files only:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^.+\.html$ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [NC,R=301,L]
```

---

**Where to place:** I would place it after domain name redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]

# your other rules
```

---

I also recommend using **rel="canonical"** links:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="PROPER_URL_HERE" />
```

- http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

---

If you do not need redirect, but rather ability to serve the file regardless of the file name case (case insensitive file names), then you can use **mod_spelling** ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html ) and `CheckCaseOnly On` directive.

Comment: "If you do not need redirect, ... you can use mod_spelling" - mod_speling (one L) will, in fact, issue a 301 redirect to the intended document.

Answer (score 3):

*Add this to the top of your .htaccess*

> SOURCE: [Htaccess to Redirect Uppercase to Lowercase](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/#Htaccess_Redirect_Uppercase_Lowercase)
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> # If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
> RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
>
> # Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
> RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
>
> # Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
> RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
> RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
> RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
> RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
> RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
> RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
> RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
> RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
> RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
> RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
> RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
> RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
> RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
> RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
> RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
> RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
> RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
> RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
> RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
> RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
> RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
> RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
> RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
> RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
> RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
> RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
>
> # If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
> RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
>
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

*Alternatively your host may support mod_speling, in which if they do, you can use in the server config, virtual host, directory or within a .htaccess file, example below:*

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckCaseOnly On
    CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer to use these 26 separate rewrite rules opposed to the two line rewrite ruling using `lc:` from LazyOne's answer?

Comment: Depends on the situation, the one I listed requires just on htaccess however the shorter version requires both virtual host and htaccess because of the initial `RewriteMap lc int:tolower` requirement.

Comment: The reason I posted this answer was because I [closed a very similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110756/how-to-redirect-any-uppercase-url-automatically-to-lowercase-using-htaccess) which asked for a htaccess only method.

Comment: This worked for me by changes within .htaccess only. Thanks!

Comment: a warning, this will re-write files as well. So if you have css or js that's mixed case, it won`t load.

Answer (score 3):

On Apache 2.4 you can convert the URL-path to lowercase in `.htaccess` (only) with an Apache Expression in a `RewriteCond` (mod_rewrite) directive. No need to define a `RewriteMap` in the server config (or write a plethora of rules to replace each letter one by one).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `[A-Z]` simply checks that there is at least one uppercase letter in the URL-path before continuing.

By passing `expr` as the *TestString* (1st arg) to the `RewriteCond` directive, the *CondPattern* (2nd arg) is treated as an Apache Expression. This performs a regex comparison which is always successful and the result of the `tolower()` function is captured by the parenthesised subpattern in the regex. This is then accessible using the `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

Note that this particular example just converts the URL-path. The query string (and hostname) remain unchanged.

The above checks every requested URL. To exclude all URLs that look like a static resource (ie. that end with what looks-like a file extension) then add a preceding condition with a negated expression. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class already includes both upper and lowercase letters, so no need for the `NC` flag here.

To specifically target just `.html` files (as mentioned in the question) then use a case-insensitive  *condition* that checks for this. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect before committing to a 301 (permanent) redirect so as to avoid potential caching issues.