# Can not get rid of duplicated title tags

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url

As I said in title, I can not get rid of duplicated titles, indexed by Google and reported in Google Webmaster tools.

Links that gives me problems are like:

```
http://www.example.com/send-gifts/e6/
http://www.example.com/send-gifts/E6/
```

I tried by adding canonical meta tag, but it's still reported as duplicated.

My canonical tag looks like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/send-gifts/e6/">
```

Can you tell me What can I do to get rid of that?

Comment: Also, this problem is caused by automatically generated pages, and also some of them are a bit old and I can not get rid of them.

Comment: How long ago did you add the canonical?  That should fix the problem, but it may take Googlebot a month or more to crawl all your pages and see that canonical on all the problem pages.

Comment: i added canonical few months ago... can redirection 301 help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using canonical tags between these two URLs, trying implementing 301 redirects.

If you can 301 redirect `/send-gifts/E6/` to `/send-gifts/e6/`, Google would certainly stop reporting duplicate titles between the pages after a full recrawl.

I would have expected canonical tags to do the job, but 301 redirects certainly will.

If all of your canonical URLs are completely lowercase, then this question should help you implement the redirects: [How to redirect any URL to lowercase URL?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/how-to-redirect-any-url-to-lowercase-url)